# Django make document filing structure + foreign keys

Tags: python, django, sqlite, file-upload, models

So... I am using `django` and `sqlite3` and am trying to create a file storage system to link in with my database. I have 2 models: **patient** and **appointment** where patient has a `1 to many` relationship with appointment. Each appointment needs to have multiple files associated with it so i created another model called 'appointmentFiles'. I want each appointment file to be uploaded to the path: patient/appointment/filename.txt . I also want it so that when i select the patient, the list of appointments to select from should be shown. It all sounds a little complex so forgive me if I didn`t explain it well enough. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume models to be like these:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    .......
    .......


class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .......
    .......

class AppointmentFiles(models.Model):
    appointment = models.ForeignKey(Appointment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ........
    ........
    path = 'uploads/'+ appointment__patient__name + '/' + appointment__id + '/'
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=path)
```

Now, it will store all files to **uploads/patient_name/appointment_number/**

where patient_name and appointment_number will vary for every patient.

Each file will be save as

> uploads/patient_name/appointment_number/filename.extension